# Hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate

i got a list from Criteria in hibernate.
after that i want to add a condition on that list

can i do that

Comment: please specify more with some code to understand the query.

Comment: Answer to the current question: yes you can.

Comment: you want to add condition on result set? why?

Comment: @Reddy my requirment is like that

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand. 
Once you got the list of entities you can do whatever you want with them.
What exactly adding a condition means? 
And if you want to restrict the result set by adding for some condition you can do that using Criteria or in the query.